# Saving data in django model don't actually saves

Tags: django, orm, save

How should I understand this? And how this can happens?
Go into django shell:

```
>>> from customauth.models import Profile
>>> p = Profile.objects.get(user_id=1)
>>> p.status
u'34566'
>>> p.status = 'qwerty'
>>> p.status
'qwerty'
>>> p.save()
>>> p.status
'qwerty'
>>> p = Profile.objects.get(user_id=1)
>>> p.status
u'qwerty'
>>>
```

Exit and go into django shell again:

```
>>> from customauth.models import Profile
>>> p = Profile.objects.get(user_id=1)
>>> p.status
u'qwerty'
>>>
```

Everything seems OK. But go into dbshell now:

```
mysql> select user_id, status from customauth_profile where user_id=1;
+---------+--------+
| user_id | status |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | 34566  |
```

Comment: May be important: I'm use django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql backend for database (need for djagno_cities app) and project hosted on Amazon whith its GPL MySQL RDS as database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in caching module. Strange, but there is no caching middleware was plugged and cache doesn't used in saving methods.
Was used `django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` module, may be its broken or has some strange features, I don't know. Will try memcached module, it should (I wish) fix problem without swithing off cache on site.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, I'm using Django and Mongo... the data wasn't persisted after `object.save()`... Them, I used it to solve:

```
object.save_base(force_update=True)
```

Now is working for me, hope can help.

Comment: I use sqlite backend, but this happened to me too in django shell. Didn't need `force_update=True` though. Super weird, cause `.save()` has never failed me before... thanks for saving my ass :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data persists after closing the shell, it is very unlikely that the data was not saved into the database. Can you check your settings.py and make sure you're saving to the correct mysql database ?

Comment: there is only one database in settings. And it was saved twice in two hours, while I trying to resolve this issue. But only twice and I don't know why... Each time it was successfully saved I tried again with no changes in code, but it was failed again.

Answer (score 0):

The shell session is a single database transaction. Connections outside that won't see the changes, because of transaction isolation. You'll need to commit the transaction - the easiest way would be to quit the shell and restart.

In a normal request, Django commits automatically at the end of the request, so this behaviour isn't an issue.

Comment: I second code block in my question  - is restarted shell session. I made changes, quit from shell and start it again. ANd it show that changes are applied.